# Can a simple buffer-overflow lead to privilege escalation?

Tags: administrator, buffer

I wanted to know, that on an OS such as windows, if someone (a non admin) writes a program in C++ specifically to get a buffer overflow, can he insert shellcode to gain admin rights, without running the app as administrator? Don't want no code, just theory

Comment: Malicious buffer overflows are almost always intended to provide additional access.  So yes.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: @LPChip I think this one can be answered authoritatively.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I agree, but this kind of question usually will result in a debate, especially since there are security patches fixing bugs, and this kind of injection requires to exploit a bug. So it becomes a yes, no game and this site just isn't the kind of site to do that.

Comment: @LPChip "Is it possible, in theory?" "Yes" and goes on to explain why and what makes it possible. I don't have the time to write up a proper answer right now unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A buffer overflow in the program itself can not lead to privilege escalation from normal user to admin. Technical reasoning about process isolation aside, imagine if it were possible. Then surely the web would be full of downloads offering "rootmywinbox.exe"

The buffer overflow would need to be in some operating system service running with elevated privileges.  Examples could be in a system service, file system code, networking code etc. This would always mean a bug in the operating system/service. Such bugs are relatively rare, but do exist. If you find one you'll be famous.

The programming language (e.g., C++) has no relevance to the question at all, unless you were referring to an overflow in the program itself, and then the answer was no.